# Getting the "Records" and "Duplicates" counts of INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

The [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)[`... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) returns as *affected-rows* a number derived from `(inserted count) + (updated count) * 2`, and this is [well documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in [multiple places](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).

However in the output of the [MySQL Command-Line Tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html), I've noticed this extra info:

```
> INSERT INTO ...
-> SELECT ... FROM ...
-> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
-> ;
Query OK, 97 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 2425  Duplicates: 28  Warnings: 0
```

Namely, the numbers `Records:` and `Duplicates:`.

Analyzing have determined:

- The `97 rows affected` is *affected-rows* (a.k.a. [`ROW_COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)).
- `Records: 2425` is the number of rows fetched by the `SELECT` part.
- `Duplicates: 28` is the number of rows actually changed by the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part.

Consequently:

- `affected-rows - Duplicates * 2` is the number of rows actually inserted.
- `Records - affected-rows - Duplicates` is the number of rows duplicated but not changed (i.e. values were set to the same value).

Which brings us to the question: **How does one obtain these numbers `Records` and `Duplicates` in a program?**  (I'm using MySQL Connector/J if that helps answer the question.)

Possibly for `Records:`, issuing a `SELECT` on [`FOUND_ROWS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) directly after the `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is one way.

I have no idea where `Duplicates:` comes from.

Comment: Following. There is a mention of `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag while connecting to [`mysql_real_connect`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) C API. It returns the number of found (matched) rows, not the number of changed rows. Maybe that can be used to derive duplicates. But this flag will have to be specifically specified while making connection. I am not sure if MySQL connector/J allows specifying additional flags.

Comment: As far as my understanding of docs, it will provide an additional information about *found (matched) rows*. You can still use `select row_count()` separately to determine the affected rows. Now using these two numbers, we may determine the remaining numbers

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I'm sorry but I can't see how you can determine the remaining numbers.  Please post an answer if you have a concrete solution.

Comment: That's why I am following this thread and suggesting some possible workouts in **comments** (not an answer) :-)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I think the value you get from specifying `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` is synonymous with `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`.  If that's the case both values can be obtained by `SELECT FOUND_ROWS(), ROW_COUNT()` regardless of `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS`.  Sure `FOUND_ROWS()` gives you the `Records:` number but I'm still at a loss as to where `Duplicates:` comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C api does not provide direct access to these values (or the underlying information to calculate these values) as numbers, as it does with [`mysql_affected_rows()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html).

You have however access to that message using [`mysql_info()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-info.html):

> **mysql_info()**
>
> `const char *mysql_info(MYSQL *mysql)`
>
> **Description**
>
> Retrieves a string providing information about the most recently executed statement, but only for the statements listed here. For other statements, mysql_info() returns NULL. The format of the string varies depending on the type of statement, as described here. The numbers are illustrative only; the string contains values appropriate for the statement.
>
> - `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`
>
>   String format: `Records: 100 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0`
> - [...]
> - `UPDATE`
>
>   String format: `Rows matched: 40 Changed: 40 Warnings: 0`
>
> **Return Values**
>
> A character string representing additional information about the most recently executed statement. NULL if no information is available for the statement.

You can/have to parse these (query dependent) strings if you need access to those values in detail. The mysql client simply displays this message as it is.

Unfortunately, not every api, including the `MySQL Connector/J`, implements or relays this feature, so those detailed values seem to not be accessable here.

Comment: For PHP: we can use [`mysqli_info()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php) function. +1

Comment: PHP specific implementation to parse the info string could be:

`preg_match_all('/(\S[^:]+): (\d+)/', $mysqli_conn_object->info, $info_points); return array_combine($info_points[1], $info_points[2]);`

Comment: +1 Oh wow, I hadn't imaged an answer so abrupt.  *The numbers are illustrative only*: I guess that means the format subject to change and parsing is at own risk.  Oh well, there doesn't seem to be a Connector/J interface anyhow.

Comment: @antak I missed that you are using java. Connector/J indeed seems to not implement this, that's a pity. I never used it, but maybe someone knows a way to access (general) server messages via Connector/J. Since no connector has more access to internal information than the c api, it would still involve parsing those messages though.